# member function call doesn´t work in Qt function "run". How I use my template in "run" correctly?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, concurrency, pointer-to-member

This is my template

```
template <class T>
void writeData(QVector<T> &vec, const QString &fp, void(T::*method_ptr)(QFile&) )
{
    QFile f(fp);
    if(!f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append) )
    {
        qDebug() << "File error" << f.error();
    }
    else
    {
        QThread::currentThread();
        for(T &tw : vec)
        {
            (tw.*method_ptr)(f);
        }
    }
    f.close();
}
```

And here I would use my template:

```
//teams is like: QVector<teamType> teams
QFuture<void> fut = run(writeData, teams, filePath, &teamType::writeTeams); // no matching function for call 'run'
                    ~~~                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//So, what´s wrong here?
```

Because this works fine:

```
writeData(teams, filePath, &teamType::writeTeams);
```

And "&teamType::writeTeams" cames from the following:

```
void teamType::writeTeams(QFile &f)
{
    QTextStream out(&f);
    out.setCodec("UTF-16LE");
    out << teamId << "\t" << offsideTrap << "\t" << withoutBall << "\t" << formationId << "\t"
            << attack << "\t" << teamMentality << "\t" << attackTactic1 << "\t"
            << attackTactic2 << "\t" << defenseTactic1 << "\t" << defenseTactic2 << "\t" << captain << "\t"
            << penaltyTakerId << "\t" << kickTakerId << "\t" << leftCornerkickTakerId << "\t" << rightCornerkickTakerId << "\t"
            << numTransfersIn << endl;
}
```

It´s a member function in class "teamType"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `writeData` is a function template there is no mechanism that `run` can use to get the correct instantiation of that template for the parameters.

A real easy fix for this is to just wrap the call in a lambda.  That would look like

```
QFuture<void> fut = run([=](){ writeData(teams, filePath, &teamType::writeTeams); });
```

and now that the call to `writeData` is actually done with the function parameters, template argument deduction will succeed and the code will compile.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try to use it with a lambda. Code compile is no problem. But the function apparently not starting, because it writes no data in the file. Strange for me. No compile errors or something. Lambda expression code: `QFuture<void> fut = run([&teams, &filePath](){ writeData(teams, filePath, &teamType::writeTeams); } );`

Comment: @M87 Not sure why.  If you add `std::cout << "inside of run function;` into the lambda, does that print for you?  If so, the lambda is getting called so it sounds like an issue with `writeData`.

Comment: @M87 Do the captures `teams` and `filePath` remain valid for the lifetime of the lambda?  No dangling references?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, Everything works fine now:

```
template <class T>
void writeTeamsForLoop(QVector<T> &vec, const QString fp, void(T::*method_ptr)(QFile&) ) 
{                                       //QString must not be a reference(const QString fp)!
    QFile f(fp);
    if(!f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append) )
    {
        qDebug() << "File error" << f.error();
    }
    else
    {
        QThread::currentThread();
        for(T &tw : vec)
        {
            (tw.*method_ptr)(f);
        }
    }
    f.close();
}
```

Lambda code:

```
QFuture<void> fut = run([&, filePath]{ writeData(teams, filePath, &teamType::writeTeams); } );
```